# How to have input with prepend text in material design lite?

Tags: css, material-design-lite

I want to have an input like this with +91 as a fixed thing.

[image]

This is the default code given on MDL Website

```
    <!-- Numeric Textfield -->
<form action="#">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield textfield-demo">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" id="sample2" />
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample2">Number...</label>
    <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Input is not a number!</span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to wrap the input in a span that you put the text in. Make the span look like an input and remove the styles from the input itself.

```css
form div.mdl-textfield input.mdl-textfield__input {
  border: 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  outline: 0;
}
form div.mdl-textfield span.wrapper {
  border: 2px inset #808080;
  font: small-caption;
}
```

```html
<!-- Numeric Textfield -->
<form action="#">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield textfield-demo">
    <span class="wrapper">+91 <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" pattern="-?[0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?" id="sample2" /></span>
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample2">Number...</label>
    <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Input is not a number!</span>
  </div>
</form>
```